# no apps can perform this action in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I got message "No apps can perform this action" in my testing phone but in tablet, it work fine. My testing phone is android version 4.2.2 and my tablet is android version 4.4.4. Here is my code.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 intent.setType("*/*");
 String[] mimetypes = {"application/pdf","text/plain","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), 3);
```

If I change in something like that,

```
     startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
```

I got this errors from my phone, but still fine in tablet.

```
  03-12 09:22:40.015: E/test(10739): Exception
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3688)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4293)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17535)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3683)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  ... 11 more
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* (has extras) }
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Activity.internalStartActivityForResult(Activity.java:3427)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Activity.access$200(Activity.java:660)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Activity$2.onStartActivity(Activity.java:3417)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForBusiness(Activity.java:5441)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3413)
  03-12 09:22:40.026: E/AndroidRuntime(10739):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3367)
```

That should work in both device and what should I do.Help me, Please.!!

Answer (score 2):

The Intent `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is only supported on devices with Android 4.4 (KitKat) and above.

Have a look at the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) docs, and specifically the one on [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).

Comment: Is there another way for android 4.2.2 ?

Comment: Not sure. If there is then there will be info in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.3 or lower, use ACTION_PICK or ACTION_GET_CONTENT as substitude.

In addition, when you invoke build-in "ACTION", you must verify there is more than one activity to receive it, if not your app may crash. Use the following code snippet to do this:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
if (isIntentSafe) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```